# Can someone help me fix this? first time trying this. AttributeError: type object 'Post' has no attribute 'published'

Tags: python, django, django-views

This is in view.py:

```py
class PostListView(ListView):
    queryset = Post.published.all()
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 4
    template_name = 'blog/post/list.html'
```

this is the model in models.py

```py
class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager, self).get_queryset().filter(status='published')
```

Comment: As the Python error is descripting, the object whose type is `Post` does not have an attribute called `published`. This is equivalent of doing `a = "Hey"` (`a` is now a type `str`) and then trying `print(a.hello)`. You will receive an `AttributeError` saying `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'hello'`.

Comment: Could you include information like what is the variable Post exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created the manager, but not assigned the manager to the model as an attribute called 'published':

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    # other fields
    published = PublishedManager()
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset) for further details and caveats.

Answer (score 0):

When you refer Post.published.all() it means you have custom [model manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/) for some field.

Are you sure you have custom manager created? Maybe you meant something like.

```
Post.objects.filter(for_example_status="pusblished")
```

Please,provide more details on models structure

Comment: Add Post model too, please.